# Update content of array and remove duplicates in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript-typings

Good day,
I have a following problem.

I have two arrays. One of them is storing items that comes from API and it goes like this:

```
0: {id: '80682ddb-0785-ec11-94f7-281878bb3ca6', name: 'test', typeId: 14, typeName: 'typename', typeAbbreviation: 'asa'}
1: {id: '80682ddb-0785-ec11-94f7-212113ca6', name: 'number 2', typeId: 14, typeName: 'typename', typeAbbreviation: 'asa'}
2: {id: '80682ddb-0785-ec11-94f7-24124878bb3ca6', name: 'number 3', typeId: 14, typeName: 'typename', typeAbbreviation: 'asa'}
```

Values from this array are used to list checkboxes.

Second array is updated every time user clicks one of the checkboxes. This checkbox is being puhsed to the table with additional checked property:

```
 0: {checked: true, id: '80682ddb-0785-ec11-94f7-281878bb3ca6', name: 'test', typeId: 14, typeName: 'typename', typeAbbreviation: 'asa'}
```

My goal is to push the values to the table - fill it with all checkboxes and then replace the certain checkbox with the selected one.
In general values from Api are replaced with certain selected checkboxes values with addional checked prop.

I tried to achieve it in a few ways using mapping, filtering and so on like that:

```
  var newArray = [];
  selectedItems?.forEach(function(mainObject) {
    for (let i=0; i<currentItems.length; i++){
         if(currentItems[i].id === mainObject.id){
            newArray.push(mainObject);
         } else {
           newArray.push(currentItems[i])
         }
    }
 });
```

I would appreciate Your help. Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you have a list that comes from an API, and you want to display it as checkboxes, and only get the ones that the user selects.
you can use map.
I think your approach is right, you should create new array, instead of trying to delete items from the original array.

```
const selectedItems = [];
const onChange = (e)=>{
     let id = e.target.value;
     if(e.target.checked){// if check box is selected
         arrayFromApi.map(item => {
         if(item.id === id){
            selectedItems.push(item);
         }
     });
     }else{// if checkbox is deselected
         selectedItems.filter(item => item.id === id);     
     }
}
```

Comment: Well, i need to fill it with selected items and the rest should be filled with non selected items